# Support for netty-tcnative in Spring Cloud Gateway 2.X

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Is it possible to use netty-tcnative to improve SSL/TLS performance with the Spring Cloud gateway 2 starter? I have search documentation and Google without luck.

I tested adding the uber jar as described in multiple places, eg. here
https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/344 but I am not seeing anything that would indicate it being used.

The netty docs show examples requiring a manual setup of the SSL Context so I'm thinking that there might be more to it. Depending on the level of Auto-Config available for this in Spring Cloud Gateway.

I also did basic benchmarks (using very lowtech `ab`) and I see no difference in performance either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the debugger I found that if I include `tcnative` as per the instructions above in https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/344 I end up with an instance of `OpenSslServerContext`.

If I leave it out I get a `JdkSslServerContext`. So my assumption is that this indicates that `tcnative` is initialised.

Still a bit confused why my benchmarks shows no performance improvement but maybe I need to give it som more load.

Comment: In production we do see a clear reduction in CPU use on the server.